# When I import a model form 3D builder , its wireframe looks weird

Tags: import

How can I solve it automatically? I import this in Obj format;
and I only get blender file , so it must be solved inside blender.

this
[image]
to this
[image]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by weird ? What do you want to do with the model ?

Comment: Do you mean it looks triangulated? This often happens where quads will become triangulated. It's all dependant on the export options that you use. What format are you exporting in? .OBJ, .FBX, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these:

Beautify Faces.
Remesh Modifier.
Limited Dissolve.
Tight Budget

Comment: Limited Dissolve works . Thank you so much :)